# Database in settings.php doesn't exist yet site is live. Where is the data?

Tags: 6, database, configuration

I've inherited a Drupal 6 site running on an Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS server. I'm trying to understand the configuration of it to create a local version of it work on.

I can't figure out how the data is being accessed. The settings file shows the following:

```
$db_url = 'mysql://root@localhost/drupal';
$db_prefix = 'dru_';
```

However when I list the databases, I can't find it:

```
mysql -u root
mysql> show databases \g
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| gitpull            |
| mysql              |
+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

In addition running drush status says it can't find it either.

```
$ drush status
SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database 'drupal'                   [warning]
```

The site is up and running so it's got to have access to the database somehow.

I figure I'm in the right directory because it's defined in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't think this can be answered without actually looking into the code base of the site. But the first thing I would check if its a multisite, or is the settings.php includes another file with the db information.

Comment: `The site is up and running so it's got to have access to the database somehow.` maybe try using [Backup and Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/node/189065/release?api_version%5B%5D=87)

Comment: Have you checked the profile folder?

Comment: First step towards exploring is checking in settings.php file. Check there if any database is connected or not.

Comment: @TonyMao good call there was a profile folder. @Alexei another good call, it is indeed multisite. Turns out there were a bunch of backups in non-intuitively named folders so I was looking in the wrong place. What worked was running `sudo find . -name settings.php` and then checking out each of the results until I found the right one.

Answer (score 0):

The hints from Tony Mao & Alexei pointed me in the right direction. It turned out there were a bunch of backups in non-intuitively named folders, so I was looking in the wrong place.

I ended up finding the right settings.php file with `sudo find . -name settings.php`.